# Can adjacent windows share a king stud to bring them closer together?

Tags: windows, framing

I am a pretty novice DIY framer, and I have a project where I am closing in my back patio.  I'd like to put three windows in the center of a wall.  I'm not looking to mull them.  I was wondering if the two windows can share a king stud, as shown below.  I've looked all over the internet, but haven't found a good answer for this.

[image: Wall w/3 Windows Side by side]

Answer (score 3):

They certainly can. In fact, you can get them closer together still, if you like, by eliminating the king stud, using one or two trimmer studs (as desired for spacing), and running a continuous header. It only needs to be as tall as it would for individual headers.

Comment: Trimmers are sized for "resistance to crushing". (Cross-grain loading cannot support as much as end-grain.)They're not randomly sized. Combining the two spans onto one trimmer could have a disastrous affect.

Comment: Clear-spanning 16', such as with an overhead door opening, calls for doubled trimmers. Girders of similar size may call for triples. This 9' span isn't a concern.

Comment: Where I live, a single trimmer is required for single story buildings. I think "resistance to crushing" has to do with "loading", and should be calculated.